# Error loading dll in path with parenthesis using ctypes (python)

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I am trying to access a dll located in the "c:/Program Files (x86)" folder in a 64-bits processor PC.

If I use os.path.exists to check if the dll exists, I receive an afirmative answer:

```
>>> print os.path.exists('c:/Program Files (x86)/Some Folder/SomeDll.dll')
True
```

But when I try to load the dll using ctypes, I get the following error:

```
>>> from ctypes import WinDLL
>>> some_dll = WinDLL('c:/Program Files (x86)/Some Folder/SomeDLL.dll')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

In 32-bit PCs the dll is located in the "c:/Program Files" folder and I can open it without problems. I think that perhaps the problem is the presence of parenthesis in the folder name. As the returned exception was a WindowsError, it seems that it is a flaw in the operating system function responsible of loading libraries.

So, the question is: how do I load a dll located in the "c:/Program Files (x86)" folder? I can't copy the dll to another destination, it **must** be located in the original path...

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried "C:/Progra~1/SomeFolder/SomeDll" ?

Another suggestion:

```
 os.chdir(r"C:\Program Files(x86)\SomeFolder")
 the_dll = WinDLL("SomeDLL.dll")
```

Comment: This is weird... If I do "dir /X Pro*.*" in the command prompt to see the short name for all the folders beginning with "Pro", 
the folder "Program Files" receives the correct short name "PROGRA~1", but the folder "Program Files (x86)" does not receive any short name, so I can not access it using a short name.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Excellent, it worked! It is a very elegant solution. How didn't I think of that before?? (-:

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I do not have 50 Rep to comment (STUPID Requirement) but `/Program Files (x86)/` is just `Progra~2` while `/Program Files/` is `Progra~1` 
Just in case Felipe Ferri reads this again :) or any one else trying to do the same.
 
NOTE: This is also assuming you do not have another long folder that starts with `Progra`, if so this can change your result - you are basically picking from an array of directories in alphabetical order - this works with any folder(s) longer than 8 characters, you take off the last two and add ~1 for first and increment for each other folder with the same set of characters.

Comment: I am sure your well past that point or else you are likely not in the business anymore :) <jokingly> 
You did already explain it above (so I knew your knowledge surpassed), I just figured I would throw in a little more detail for other situations, different folder names ect. and hopefully anyone else having a problem will find use in it.