# how to solve OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found when importing geopandas?

Tags: python, python-3.7, geopandas

I get the following error when importing geopandas:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\s160873\Documents\spyder\untitled7.py", line 2, in <module>
    import geopandas as gpd

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries  # noqa

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py", line 10, in <module>
    from shapely.geometry.base import BaseGeometry

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .base import CAP_STYLE, JOIN_STYLE

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\base.py", line 18, in <module>
    from shapely.coords import CoordinateSequence

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\coords.py", line 8, in <module>
    from shapely.geos import lgeos

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geos.py", line 145, in <module>
    _lgeos = CDLL(os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'Library', 'bin', 'geos_c.dll'))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I have installed the GDAL, Fiona, pyproj, rtree and shapely wheels as sugested here "[Install Python geopandas failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51095970/install-python-geopandas-failed)"

Any help is appreciated.