# ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Layout: 'autotypenumbers'

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am trying to plot the following directly from an example online (listed below). I have geopandas, GDAL, fiona, shapely, rtree, and pyproj all installed based off of the recommendations in this [Install Python geopandas failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51095970/install-python-geopandas-failed) .

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv",
                   dtype={"fips": str})

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, geojson=counties, locations='fips', color='unemp',
                           color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                           range_color=(0, 12),
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                           zoom=3, center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129},
                           opacity=0.5,
                           labels={'unemp':'unemployment rate'}
                          )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

It is code pulled directly from: https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/
[image]

I keep getting this error. Can someone help me understand what I need to do to fix this.

```
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-102-d2bce8a3a6d7> in <module>
         10 import plotly.express as px
         11 
    ---> 12 fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, geojson=counties, locations='fips', color='unemp',
         13                            color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
         14                            range_color=(0, 12),
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_chart_types.py in choropleth_mapbox(data_frame, geojson, featureidkey, locations, color, hover_name, hover_data, custom_data, animation_frame, animation_group, category_orders, labels, color_discrete_sequence, color_discrete_map, color_continuous_scale, range_color, color_continuous_midpoint, opacity, zoom, center, mapbox_style, title, template, width, height)
       1139     hover_data=None,
       1140     custom_data=None,
    -> 1141     animation_frame=None,
       1142     animation_group=None,
       1143     category_orders=None,
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_core.py in make_figure(args, constructor, trace_patch, layout_patch)
       2051     layout_patch["legend"] = dict(tracegroupgap=0)
       2052     if trace_name_labels:
    -> 2053         layout_patch["legend"]["title_text"] = ", ".join(trace_name_labels)
       2054     if args["title"]:
       2055         layout_patch["title_text"] = args["title"]
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in update_layout(self, dict1, overwrite, **kwargs)
        963         return self["data"]
        964 
    --> 965     @data.setter
        966     def data(self, new_data):
        967 
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in update(self, dict1, overwrite, **kwargs)
       4254         # ### _change_callbacks ###
       4255         # A dict from tuples of child property path tuples to lists
    -> 4256         # of callbacks that should be executed whenever any of these
       4257         # properties is modified
       4258         self._change_callbacks = {}
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in _perform_update(plotly_obj, update_obj, overwrite)
       3347 
       3348         # Handle layout
    -> 3349         # -------------
       3350         result["layout"] = BaseFigure._to_ordered_dict(self._layout)
       3351 
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in __setitem__(self, prop, value)
       4993             if invalid_props:
       4994                 if len(invalid_props) == 1:
    -> 4995                     prop_str = "property"
       4996                     invalid_str = repr(invalid_props[0])
       4997                 else:
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in __setitem__(self, prop, value)
       4009             annotation, shape_type, shape_args, annotation_kwargs
       4010         )
    -> 4011         self.add_shape(
       4012             row=row,
       4013             col=col,
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in _set_compound_prop(self, prop, val)
       4394                 from _plotly_utils.basevalidators import (
       4395                     CompoundValidator,
    -> 4396                     CompoundArrayValidator,
       4397                 )
       4398 
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py in validate_coerce(self, v, skip_invalid)
       2737         if v == {} or isinstance(v, self.data_class) and v.to_plotly_json() == {}:
       2738             # Replace empty template with {'data': {'scatter': [{}]}} so that we can
    -> 2739             # tell the difference between an un-initialized template and a template
       2740             # explicitly set to empty.
       2741             return self.data_class(data_scatter=[{}])
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py in validate_coerce(self, v, skip_invalid, _validate)
       2448 
       2449         elif isinstance(v, dict):
    -> 2450             v = self.data_class(v, skip_invalid=skip_invalid, _validate=_validate)
       2451 
       2452         elif isinstance(v, self.data_class):
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\layout\_template.py in __init__(self, arg, data, layout, **kwargs)
        321         _v = layout if layout is not None else _v
        322         if _v is not None:
    --> 323             self["layout"] = _v
        324 
        325         # Process unknown kwargs
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in __setitem__(self, prop, value)
       4009             annotation, shape_type, shape_args, annotation_kwargs
       4010         )
    -> 4011         self.add_shape(
       4012             row=row,
       4013             col=col,
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in _set_compound_prop(self, prop, val)
       4394                 from _plotly_utils.basevalidators import (
       4395                     CompoundValidator,
    -> 4396                     CompoundArrayValidator,
       4397                 )
       4398 
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py in validate_coerce(self, v, skip_invalid, _validate)
       2444 
       2445     def validate_coerce(self, v, skip_invalid=False, _validate=True):
    -> 2446         if v is None:
       2447             v = self.data_class()
       2448 
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\_layout.py in __init__(self, arg, activeshape, angularaxis, annotations, annotationdefaults, autosize, bargap, bargroupgap, barmode, barnorm, boxgap, boxgroupgap, boxmode, calendar, clickmode, coloraxis, colorscale, colorway, datarevision, direction, dragmode, editrevision, extendfunnelareacolors, extendpiecolors, extendsunburstcolors, extendtreemapcolors, font, funnelareacolorway, funnelgap, funnelgroupgap, funnelmode, geo, grid, height, hiddenlabels, hiddenlabelssrc, hidesources, hoverdistance, hoverlabel, hovermode, images, imagedefaults, legend, mapbox, margin, meta, metasrc, modebar, newshape, orientation, paper_bgcolor, piecolorway, plot_bgcolor, polar, radialaxis, scene, selectdirection, selectionrevision, separators, shapes, shapedefaults, showlegend, sliders, sliderdefaults, spikedistance, sunburstcolorway, template, ternary, title, titlefont, transition, treemapcolorway, uirevision, uniformtext, updatemenus, updatemenudefaults, violingap, violingroupgap, violinmode, waterfallgap, waterfallgroupgap, waterfallmode, width, xaxis, yaxis, **kwargs)
       6096         _v = funnelmode if funnelmode is not None else _v
       6097         if _v is not None:
    -> 6098             self["funnelmode"] = _v
       6099         _v = arg.pop("geo", None)
       6100         _v = geo if geo is not None else _v
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in _process_kwargs(self, **kwargs)
       4850         prop : str
       4851             The name of a direct child of this object
    -> 4852         value
       4853             New property value
       4854         Returns
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in _process_kwargs(self, **kwargs)
       3547             If True, produce a string containing a complete HTML document
       3548             starting with an <html> tag.  If False, produce a string containing
    -> 3549             a single <div> element.
       3550         animation_opts: dict or None (default None)
       3551             dict of custom animation parameters to be passed to the function
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in _raise_on_invalid_property_error(self, *args)
       4215             Invalid props/values to raise on
       4216         """
    -> 4217         # ### _skip_invalid ##
       4218         # If True, then invalid properties should be skipped, if False then
       4219         # invalid properties will result in an exception
    
    ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Layout: 'autotypenumbers'
```

Comment: what version of plotly are you using, using the latest version is working perfectly fine for me

Comment: @AS11 plotly-4.14.3

Comment: This may just be a problem that is caused by another package, maybe try running this in an environment with only the requirements that are needed for this specific file.

Comment: I need to isolate the failure. First, let's see if we can display other maps in plotly. Let's start with this [one](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#choropleth-map-using-geojson). [Here](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Layout.html) is the description of the parameter 'autontypenumbers', which is the error message. Let's try :`px.choropleth_mapbox(...,autotypenumbers='strict')`.