# Can't load .dll in python using ctype

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I have read almost all of the entries here on SO, still the module wont load.

Here is my code

```
myDll = cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\\Users\\GODWIN\\Desktop\\libavformat\\libavformat-56.dll")
```

and this is the error it gives

```
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Comment: Seems strange that you are using both a raw string and double back-slashes - there is no need for both but I can't say if that is the issue since I can't try it:  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940578/windowserror-error-126-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found

Comment: Thanks it is not.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure: Is there actually a file at `C:\\Users\\GODWIN\\Desktop\\libavformat\\libavformat-56.dll`? Can you put it in the address bar in Windows Explorer and it opens a file? I would assume "of course", but you never know.

Comment: @pydude yes there is.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

`windll.LoadLibrary()`

It depends on the calling convention of the dll.

`__cdecl and __stdcall`

edit:

After further investigation I noticed that it's most likely due to the path format. Try forward slashes or raw string format.

edit2:

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940578/windowserror-error-126-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found) you should install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015

Comment: `windll` and `cdll` won't matter if the DLL won't load.  They just select the default calling convention of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

If your path is accurate, you are missing a dependency DLL.  Use a tool like `dumpbin` to determine the dependencies or `Process Monitor` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650202/235698) for an example).