# best_local_affine_kernel.cu [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found on Windows 10

Tags: python, cuda, cupy

I am running FastPhotoStyle code on Windows 10 and using Python 3.7, CUDA 10.0 and cuda 9.1. Although I made the change that was suggested to upgrade the version of Python from string to Byte, I am still getting the same error. Can you please suggest a fix for this issue.

```
Resize image: (803,538)->(803,538)

Resize image: (960,540)->(960,540)

Elapsed time in stylization: 2.325060

Elapsed time in propagation: 83.987388

Elapsed time in post processing: 0.015629

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "demo.py", line 47, in 
no_post=args.no_post
File "D:\TrainImages\FastPhotoStyle-master\process_stylization.py", line 135, in stylization

out_img = smooth_filter(out_img, cont_pilimg, f_radius=15, f_edge=1e-1)
File "D:\TrainImages\FastPhotoStyle-master\smooth_filter.py", line 402, in smooth_filter

best_ = smooth_local_affine(output_, input_, 1e-7, 3, H, W, f_radius, f_edge)
File "D:\TrainImages\FastPhotoStyle-master\smooth_filter.py", line 333, in smooth_local_affine

    program = Program(src.encode('utf-8'),best_local_affine_kernel.cu'.encode('utf-8'))
File "C:\Users\SD\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pynvrtc\compiler.py", line 49, in init
self._interface = NVRTCInterface(lib_name)

File "C:\Users\SD\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pynvrtc\interface.py", line 87, in init
self._load_nvrtc_lib(lib_path)

File "C:\Users\SD\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pynvrtc\interface.py", line 109, in _load_nvrtc_lib
self.lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(name)

File "C:\Users\SD\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes_init.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
return self.dlltype(name)

File "C:\Users\SD\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes_init.py", line 356, in init
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I have already changed string to bytes

```
program = Program(src.encode('utf-8'), 'best_local_affine_kernel.cu'.encode('utf-8'))
ptx = program.compile(['-I/usr/local/cuda/include'.encode('utf-8')])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WindowsError: \[Error 126\] The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940578/windowserror-error-126-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check the documentation here --> https://github.com/NVIDIA/FastPhotoStyle/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md

The above link specifies setup on Ubuntu but there are prerequites for Python modules as well that you should have installed on your machine.

Comment: Yes, I realized now that they have hard-coded paths in the code for Ubuntu