# how to solve the ddl and libraray path problem in python with module not found

Tags: python, package, jupyter, ddl, openslide

i want to use openslide library in code , installed it but in jupyter notebook ,it is giving error for module not found..:
when import openslide it gives the following error:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openslide\__init__.py in <module>
     27 from PIL import Image
     28 
---> 29 from openslide import lowlevel
     30 
     31 # For the benefit of library users

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openslide\lowlevel.py in <module>
     39 
     40 if platform.system() == 'Windows':
---> 41     _lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('libopenslide.0.dll')
     42 elif platform.system() == 'Darwin':
     43     try:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in LoadLibrary(self, name)
    432 
    433     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 434         return self._dlltype(name)
    435 
    436 cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    354 
    355         if handle is None:
--> 356             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    357         else:
    358             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Comment: from what I see the DLL is not in your system (windows) PATH

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WindowsError: \[Error 126\] The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940578/windowserror-error-126-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)