# Glumpy Error 'OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found'

Tags: python, ctypes, glfw, pyopengl, glumpy

I've just started using glumpy and I keep having an error.

As far as I could find out there is a problem in ctypes module. apparently the ctype module is trying to load a `dll` file and it can't for a reason. 
the peace of code I've written is as follow.

```
from glumpy import app,gl,gloo
app.use("glfw")
window = app.Window()
```

The error I keep having is as follows:

```
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I've tried finding the `dll` file directory but I don't know from where it is trying to load that `dll` file

Comment: These modules aren't built-in you have to install it through `pip`. The reason why you are getting the error because the module isn't installed.

Comment: I had installed all the needed modules. which module do you mean?

Comment: I found the problem.. The problem is that your code is trying to load a dll which failed. More info can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940578/windowserror-error-126-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940578/windowserror-error-126-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found

Comment: but in this case, I don't know where is that `.dll` file and how can I fix it. `glumpy` is probably calling `cytpes` and `ctypes` is calling the dll directory and the dll directory has some issues. I don't know what to do to fix my problem. should I edit ctypes code?